# Python Reference Appending List

Tags: python

Im a bit baffled how this works.

```
x = []
y = []
for i in range(5):
    y.append(i) # Why does this create full copies of sub lists?
    x.append(y)
    #x.extend(y) # This works normal

print x
```

Why is `x.append(y)` cauusing the final result to be the following? Could you please explain if there is some background reference values going on?

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one object pointed to by `y`. It starts as an empty list. Each time through the loop, you are making that single object longer. The list `x` is essentially the same as `[y, y, y, y, y]`, which gives you the result you describe.

When you use `x.extend(y)`, then the *current* elements of `y` are copied onto the end of the list `x`. This is a totally different operation.